# Animated texture quality very bad

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to create a short opener for a clip by using a plane and an animated texture. I created the animated texture sheet, frame by frame, in photoshop. It's a large texture, 12x12 frames. When I try playing it in unity, while it works, it is of a significantly lower quality.

I have seen posts about tweaking my import settings, but these are the only ones I see (no max size etc)

[image]

I did have to use an older version of unity to make it work with the rest of the project I was working on - is that the problem? I feel like even older versions should be capable of generating good quality

Comment: change filter mode

Comment: Click the "default" button to change the default settings instead of platform-specific ones.

Comment: What is the dimension of your texture in photoshop? If it's larger than 2048, then your imported texture in unity will be of lower quality. So might have to increase the "Max size" to 4096 or 8192, which is not recommended for mobiles though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable mipmaps. [Mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) are downsized versions of your texture used for rendering at different distances. If the distance you have your image from the camera is far enough, Unity will use one of those smaller versions, making it blurry.
2. Disable blend mode (set it to 'Point'). [Bilinear Filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering) slightly blurs textures so that they scale better or render at sub-pixel positioning better. However, this makes them less crisp.
3. You may want to set the texture mode from 'Default' to 'Sprite 2D' or 'GUI', I'm not sure what version of Unity you're on (2017?) as I don't recognize the layout of the inspector you have there.  Sprite 2D settings tend to optimize for images that are intended to be pixel perfect, same goes for GUI textures.